# Fancy Dispersion / Diamond material looks sadly underwhelming and dull in render

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting, glass

I am working on a high heel shoe model (See picture below) that has two straps with each around 600 tiny diamond shaped crystals on it. I am using a high quality shader, that has yielded good results in other situations, however, I don't get it shine in my scene. The diamonds are multipied on a mesh through a particle system.
I fiddled around with the scene scale, different lighting setups (point/spot lights, HDRIs, etc), ramping up the light paths (global illumination) didn't resolve and is also not a great solutions, since it's going to explode the render times. Rendering in cycles.
Grateful for any pointers! Thank you!

ps. blender file: [image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think without actual file and desired result, people here can help ... it is definitely about light condition (lamp, reflections, environment) ... also there ca be some issue with shader it self that works better with some internal setup in different scale than in your case ... so probably better share file via https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: maybe add strong lights and also some effects like bloom in Eevee or glare/blur in the Compositor?

Comment: added a scene file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=GOYNbm2L" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GOYNbm2L/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cycles

Your diamonds look quite different in your image than what I got from your shared file ...

**Cycles** (12 samples)
[image]

Since the final effect remains on all materials and environment you could keep also leather materials to see how it affects result - reflection from material behind could be important.

So for a tests I added leather simple color and will follow your given file ...

**Cycles** (1024 samples)
[image]

"Black" looking diamonds in render are artefacts generated by overlapping particles. Your upper emitter object has 295 vertices, but your particle system is set to emit 683 diamonds. If you match particles with number of vertices, than issue is gone.

[image]

Now you are facing to another issue - leather visible at a centre of each diamond, because the tip of diamond penetrates into the leather. So you would have to avoid that in some way ... here I just set *Shrinkwrap* > *Offset* -0.001

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since for cycles it could take a lot of time to calculate clean render with all the refractions (or what ever ...), consider to use ...

### Eevee

**Eevee** (with Bloom) - your studio environment
[image]

**Eevee** (with Bloom) - blender's studio.exr
[image]

**Eevee** (with Bloom) - blender's courtyard.exr
[image]

---

**Footnotes**:

- I don't know how about diamonds, but what I saw with bijou - crystals are placed into a glossy silver holder or galvanised by silver material on back sides to create like a mirror surface ... so they appear very shiny even gluwed at dark surface.
- In Outliner editor you have some object disabled for Viewport but still enabled for rendering ... so just be sure it is set as you really want to be.

Comment: thanks @vklidu highly appreciated. i removed the all other materials to decrease the file size. it was too big before. i know eeve does a quick and fairly ok job, but the cycles renderer seems to give a more accuracy. still there are a lot of gemstones that stay dark and don't catch any light. here's a reference images: https://www.ebay.com/itm/175332111226
also, my eeve result doesn't look like yours in the render. is there anything else that you did to the scene? cheers!

Comment: Also your reference is a full of black diamonds (blacks in my first image can be just I used 1ě samples :) ... your image looks flat, yes, are you sure World was set to your studio (Lightbox) texture? Looks more like greenish reflection of blender's forest.exr ... eve I think I add only Bloom (I will edit the A with setup ... I have also one more thing in mind to extend my answer (I'm not sure it make a difference :)

Comment: If you would need my blend I can share ... just let me know :)

Comment: Sorry, for the slow response. I've been away over the weekend. Thank you, you are amazing. I was suspecting that it has to do with the tips of the diamonds penetrating the leather material. If you don't mind, please share the file with me. Thanks again!

Comment: Temp link https://we.tl/t-DYZjiThHyU Good luck with your project :)